# Visitor Pattern: different ways to visit the same structure

Tags: c#, visitor-pattern

I have this kind of table strucutre:

```
public class Table : IVisitable
{
    public List<Row> rows;
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach(Row row in rows)
            row.accept(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Row : IVisitable
{
    public List<Cell> columns; 
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach(Cell cell in columns)
            cell.accept(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
public class Cell : IVisitable
{
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {visitor.visit(this);}
}
```

A Parser will create the object of this classes, so I'm kinda hand-tied about extending classes or something like that (but I could reconsider that in front of a **good** solution).

Now, as you can see the `accept()` method which I implemented **visit the whole table**, but now I want to define a visitor which visit only the first 2 lines of the table. How can I do that without adding an another `accept()`?

**UPDATE:**
I thought about this solution, and I'd like to have your opinion. Without rewrite the whole code above, just imagine that each class doesn't implement the IVisitable interface (and so no accept() for each class). What about creating two classes which extend Table? Something like this:

```
public class VisitTwoRowTable : Table,IVisitable
{
    public VisitTwoRowTable(Table table)
    {
        foreach(Row row in table.rows)
              this.rows.add(row);
    }        
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            row[i].accept(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

And this other one:

```
public class VisitWholeTable : Table,IVisitable
{
    public VisitWholeTable(Table table)
    {
        foreach(Row row in table.rows)
              this.rows.add(row);
    }
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach(Row row in rows)
            row.accept(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

The only **REALLY UGLY** thing of this solution is the constructor part, where it creates a copy (shallow copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a state to your visitor and keep track of the number of rows you already visited.

Given these types (I omitted Cell for brevity):

```
public interface IVisitor
{
    void visit(Row v);
    void visit(Table v);
}

public interface IVisitable
{
    void accept(IVisitor visitor);
}

public class Table : IVisitable
{
    public List<Row> rows;
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach(Row row in rows)
            row.accept(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Row : IVisitable
{
    public int number;
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

your visitor could look like:

```
public class FirstTwoRowVisitor : IVisitor
{
    int _numOfRows = 0;

    public void visit(Row r)    
    { 
        if (_numOfRows == 2)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Visited Row #{0}", r.number);
        _numOfRows++;
    }

    public void visit(Table t)  
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Table has {0} Rows total", t.rows.Count);
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
var t = new Table() { rows = new List<Row>() };
int i = 0;
t.rows.Add(new Row() {number = i++});
t.rows.Add(new Row() {number = i++});
t.rows.Add(new Row() {number = i++});
t.rows.Add(new Row() {number = i++});
var v = new FirstTwoRowVisitor();
t.accept(v);
```

will output

```
Visited Row #0
Visited Row #1
Table has 4 Rows total
```

(This is of course just a simple example and each instance will only ever be able to process two rows; but you can alter it depending on your needs)

---

**In response to your comment:**

```
public interface IVisitor
{
    void visit(Row v);
    void visit(Table v);
    bool keepgoing { get; }
}

public class Table : IVisitable
{
    public List<Row> rows;
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach(Row row in rows)
            if (visitor.keepgoing) row.accept(visitor);
            else break;
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class FirstTwoRowVisitor : IVisitor
{
    int _numOfRows = 0;

    public bool keepgoing { get { return _numOfRows < 2; } }

    public void visit(Row r)    
    { 
        if (!keepgoing)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Visited Row #{0}", r.number);
        _numOfRows++;
    }

    public void visit(Table t)  
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Table has {0} Rows total", t.rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is the best solution that I had thoguht too until now, but it's not the best solution in terms of performance, but if nothing better will come out I think that I will go with this one.

Comment: Anyway I just added the UPDATE section, maybe you could give it a look ;)

Comment: Subclassing just to implement the `IVisitable` interface seems very very ugly to me. Could you elaborate were there's a performance problem with my solution? Anyway, are you sure you actually need the visitor pattern here?

Comment: @justHelloWorld I really dislike the code in your update. You create two new classes that subclass `Table` when you really want to have two different visitors, one that visits the whole table, and one which visits only two rows.

Comment: In fact I prefer your solution too :P However not necesserily, but I have to create 3 code generator, so visitor pattern could be really useful, and in addiction it's the first time that I'm using it, so I think that's good practice anyway :)

Comment: the performance are not so perfect since you have to visit ALL the rows, even if from the 3th the cost is trivial. Anyway, the algorithm cost is O(n) instead of O(1), do you agree with me?

Comment: @justHelloWorld Agree. However, if this becomes a *real* problem, you could alter the visitor to indicate if it accepts further row. See my update for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the

```
foreach (Row row in rows)
    row.accept(visitor);
```

into the `visitor.Visit(table)` method

Then provide different implementations of this in different visitors, e.g. change it in your new visitor to

```
foreach (Row row in rows.Take(2))
    row.accept(visitor);
```

(You would also have to make rows public on your Table class.)

Comment: I thought about a solution like this one you proposed, but if I'm not wrong you're not allowed to explore the structure visited, since the element visited should not know "what is its structure" in order to be more independent. I know that you can do it in some particular cases, but I don't think this is one of them :)

Comment: Anyway I just added the UPDATE section, maybe you could give it a look ;)

Comment: I'm not too keen on your solution, the point of the visitor pattern is to separate the data from the visiting, either of my or sloth's solutions would be preferable imho